# Can progressive web app do server side calculation when internet is off

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWA and also searched to find the answer but was not successful.

I know that PWA can handle all database transactions when internet is off by using indexdb.

For consistency I need to do some of the calculation at server side but wonder if by using PWA I can handle those calculations locally too  or not.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Technically, yes. That would require you to place the calculation logic that exists on the server, on the client as well. You would have to check if the client has connectivity; if it does not, perform the calculations on the client device. Otherwise, send the request to the server to perform the calculation. Keep in mind that if the calc. is intensive, then the user will notice a slow-down or bottleneck b/c of the potential for high resource consumption on the client device.

Comment: @Evan, Thanks for your answer, does it mean that I have to write the calculation codes again at client side ( this is something that I am trying not to do for consistency ) or there are features in PWA that can manage it?

Comment: This is something that you would have to write client-side as well. A PWA isn't going to store server-side code/logic. You have to design your PWA so that all functionality (that you want to be available offline) is preserved when the client is offline.

Comment: @albertsh you can avoid code duplication if you will use node.js. In that case you can reuse same function on server and client side.

Comment: @Arseniy-II, Thanks for you answer, I have a project already developed by asp.net using sql server. We are going to develop few web services to manage the calculation on server side, all the calculations will be done inside the web service not in sql server.can you please clarify more that how node.js can help us here. I would appreciate if you send the links that may be helpful.

Comment: @albertsh I have posted answer to explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid code duplication if you will use node.js. In that case you can reuse same function on server and client side

For example: You can write file `summ.js` like this:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

module.exports = sum;
```

after that you can import it to use on FE:

```
import sum from './sum'

console.log(sum(1,2));
```

or create node.js file `handleSum.js` on BE:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

console.log(sum(1, 2));
```

and you can execute your `handle.js` like this: `node handleSum.js`

Comment: Thanks for your great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best in terms of architecture design to have the calculations done either server-side or client-side, but not both. For maintainability, consider the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

So in your case, consider the need for the calculations both locally and server-sided. Why does it need to be on either of those sides? If the server performs calculations and then stores the result, you can use the background sync principles to delay the sending off the data and have the result calculated and stored when needed.

When the client immediately requires the result of the calculation, consider doing the calculations only locally and send the result to the server with background sync when a a connection is available again.

If you absolutely do need the calculations on both the client and the server, consider an architecture where the module that performs the calculations can be used both locally as server-sided. This is possible when both the server and the client use JavaScript, i.e. NodeJS. Then you can import this module server sided and download + cache the module client sided.